# Getting error while trying to authenticate gcloud with json

Tags: json, docker, gcloud

So I have the gcloud docker image and want to use gcloud through the image, but I need to authenticate and I'm getting this error.

`ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Could not read json file credentials.json: Invalid control character`

and these are the commands I'm using

`echo -n "$GOOGLE_TOKEN" > /tmp/credentials.json
      - cat /tmp/credentials.json
      - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/tmp/credentials.json`

and the service account json does work on other apps.

Comment: What is $GOOGLE_TOKEN in your case? Is it access/refresh token?

Comment: Its a system environment var of the service account json @cherba

Comment: From the error does not look like `credentials.json` is valid json file. Does the following print the content of this file: `python -c "import json; print(json.load(open('/tmp/credentials.json')))"` and does it have `'client_id': ...` in the output.

Comment: @cherba Looks like the /n in the json doesn't like echo so it becomes a unauthorized character so i fixed it by putting // at each /n

Answer (score 7):

"echo" is not portable. In some cases it does \X escape processing by default. It depends on the system and/or shell variant and/or shell release. Use printf instead of "echo -n ...":

`printf '%s' "$GOOGLE_TOKEN"`

Comment: Thank you man, it worked! I got this issue with gcloud with nodejs:latest image, i couldn't authenticate in local or with CloudBuild. Many thanks!